# How to rename a file with a specific pattern using the jenkins fileOperations plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I rename a file in Jenkins that follows the pattern `MyFile>VersionNumber<.txt` where the part >VersionNumber< is variable. The target name is fix and doesn't include the version number.

Unfortunatly this doesn't work for a file like `MyFile_v12.1.4.txt`:

```
 fileOperations([fileRenameOperation(source: '*.txt', destination: 'MyFile.txt')])
```

Here the failure message:

```
 FATAL: The source file/var/jenkins_home/workspace/*.txt doesn't exist.

 File Operations failed.
```

Comment: Where is your file located in the jenkins workspace? It simply can't find the file. 'source' is depending on the Jenkins workspace.

Comment: The source file is in the right place. At least is works if I use the real filename without wild card.

Comment: You can also use a simple shell or batch command (like mv) to rename the file. No need to use a plugin.

Comment: The down side is that a command is platform dependent, which is an issue in my case.

Comment: Any update on this @Chriss ??